# Is it mandatory to inject AngularJs service at first parameter in a function which has another parameters?

Tags: angularjs

I have recently started learning AngularJs. I got errors while inject AngularJs service in a function. Later I have figured out that I need to follow the order when I inject service with other parameters in the function. I just wanted to know why we need to follow the order?

Comment: Dependency Injection is [very well documented](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#!).

Comment: Now I understand. Thanks a lot